# What is the effect of using np.dot on two vectors?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, machine-learning, matrix-multiplication

This problem is to do with the numpy library.

From previous experience np.dot is the same as matrix multiplication. However I was under the assumption that multiplying two vectors is impossible as the dimensionality is wrong. So my question is, what does np.dot actually do to two vectors?

Furthermore, say I had the following code and assuming np.dot produces a scalar (as it says on the documentation).

```
x= np.dot(dc, self.c)[:self.ys]
```

where x is also a vector, how does the operation [:self.ys] change the result of the two vectors in an np.dot into a vector? I cannot find anything detailing on this.

Comment: The first part of the question is answered in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html): "...  *for 1-D arrays to **inner product of vectors** * ...". The second part is unclear. Please provide a complete code example (get rid of `self` and define the variables used).

Comment: I'm working on a lstm neural network in a .Net language and am using this python code as an example to work from. x = derivative of hidden state (vector), dc = derivative of cell state (vector), self.c = cell-state in timestep tS (vector), self.ys = output size (int)

Comment: My question is, if the np.dot produces a scalar, but x is a vector how does [:ys] convert the scalar into a vector?

Comment: That's the crux... `[ ]` does not convert a scalar in a vector. It gives an error `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.` if `dot` returns a scalar. So either the code is wrong or the input is not what you think.

Comment: The full source is [link](https://github.com/llSourcell/LSTM_Networks/blob/master/LSTM%20Demo.ipynb) both dc and c appear to be vectors. However I may have misunderstood what self does as there is one variable called c at an lstm class level (an array) and another at the method level (vector).

Answer (score 1):

numpy.dot performs a "dot" or inner product between two products. However, it also performs an operation called *broadcasting* that is common to many languages (except matlab rebrands the dimension matching part as *implicit expansion*). In this case the dimensions are completed to a matching product automatically for convenience and performance. More explanation is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

`[:self.ys]` is a slice. Suppose the value of `self.ys` is 5. Then it means take the result of the dot product and only assign the first 5 items to `x` since Python uses zero indexing. You can omit the starting number if it is zero hence it is also for convenience. `[a:b]` is `[a,a+1,...,b-1]` if `a` is 0 then you can leave it out and it is assumed.

Comment: If the result of dot product is a scalar though how can it take the first ys items?

Comment: @AlexMcKinney If `dc` is a column vector the result is a matrix. Look at the result first.

Comment: I think they are both column vectors. Although here is the full source [here](https://github.com/llSourcell/LSTM_Networks/blob/master/LSTM%20Demo.ipynb) does have two variables named c, one being an array and the other a vector. I might have misunderstood what self does.

Comment: @AlexMcKinney Insert some `print`s in the class code. So you can see what arguments come in.

Answer (score 0):

numpy.dot() function returns the dot product of two arrays. For 2-D vectors, it is the equivalent to matrix multiplication. For 1-D arrays, it is the inner product of the vectors. For Ndimensional arrays, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and the second-last axis of b.

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_dot.htm